# MapStruct with XSI Type mapping

Tags: mapping, mapstruct, xsitype

I am new to map struct. I am try to convert JSON to XML. My XML component looking for XSI type. I have done the custom mapping with the cast the XSI type object. But the XML is missing the XSI type. which is leading in the sub systems.

```
default com.test.sales.types.Order map(com.test.order.types.Order value) {
    if (value != null) {
        com.test.sales.types.Order mapping = null;
        if (value instanceof com.test.order.types.X)
            mapping = map((com.test.order.types.X) value);
        else if (value instanceof com.test.order.types.Y)
            mapping = map((com.test.order.types.Y) value);
        return mapping;
    }
    return null;
};
```

Comment: What do you mean with the XSI type is missing? MapStruct maps into Objects not into XML. Can you show us a better example with the actual code which is wrong?

Comment: <order xsi:type="X> .... </order>
<order xsi:type="Y> .... </order>

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine if you set the object on the root element object.

```
default com.test.sales.types.X mapX(com.test.order.types.Order value) {
    com.test.sales.types.Order mapping = 
        mapping = map((com.test.order.types.X) value);
    return mapping;
```

};

```
default com.test.sales.types.Y mapY(com.test.order.types.Order value) {
    com.test.sales.types.Order mapping = 
        mapping = map((com.test.order.types.Y) value);
    return mapping;
```

};

```
default com.test.sales.types.Sales map(com.test.order.types.Sales data) {
com.test.sales.types.Sales returns = new com.test.sales.types.Sales();


if (data.getOrder().getIsXObj()) {
returns.setOrder(mapX(data.getOrder()));
```

} else {

```
returns.setOrder(mapY(data.getOrder()));
```

}
}